# Using space as delimiter in boost::char_separator

Tags: c++, boost

I'm just trying to tokenize some time using Boost.
I want to input `5:00 PM` and output `<5> <00> <PM>`. 
The problem is that I've tried all sorts of things, but it only outputs `<5> <00>`.
However, if I input `5:00PM`, I get the output `<5> <00PM>`. How can I make boost accept space as a token (alongside :)? It just keeps throwing the PM when the PM is separated from 00 by a space.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
using namespace std;
int main(){

    string str1;
cin >>  str1;

typedef boost::tokenizer<boost::char_separator<char> > 
tokenizer;

boost::char_separator<char> sep(":\t ");

string t1 (str1);
tokenizer tokens1(t1, sep);
  for (tokenizer::iterator tok_iter = tokens1.begin();
   tok_iter != tokens1.end(); tok_iter++)
  {cout << "<" << *tok_iter << "> ";}



system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What output are you expecting? `<5> <00> <PM>`?

Comment: I want the output `<5> <00> <PM>` but I have no idea how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It just keeps throwing the PM when the PM is separated from 00 by a space.

It's not throwing. `PM` just doesn't exist in the `str1`, since `std::cin` use space as delimeter too. Replace

```
cin >>  str1;
```

With

```
std::getline(std::cin, str1);
```